# Trying to get ORF's from a given DNA sequence

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I am trying to get a printed output which would be everything from the beginning of the string, to the end, which is until it reaches a certain series of characters like "TAA", "TAG", or "TGA".
I can't get it to work and was wondering if anyone here can help me??

```
def get_orf(dna):
'''Function should take an argument (string) and find an ORF'''
stopVar = "TAA" or "TGA" or "TAG"
if argument[0:3] == "ATG":
    return
else: 
    return ""
if stopVar in argument:
    return argument[:argument.find(stopVar)]
else:
    return argument
    
return

# Test Cases
#
# You may wish to add more test cases here
argument = 'ATGTGAA'
computed_result = get_orf( argument )
expected_result = 'ATG'
if ( computed_result == expected_result ):
    print ("Test Case 1: Passed")
else:
    print ("Test Case 1: Failed")
    print ("Expected Result:", expected_result)
    print ("Computed Result:", computed_result)
```

Comment: Your function `get_orf` argument name is `dna` yet you are using `argument` in the code. Change `dna` to `argument` in the `get_orf` code or vice versa and then come back here and edit into the question if it is still not working.

Comment: Well, the function name and the parameters were already given to me. Though I did change the parameter to 'argument', nothing changed.

Comment: When you have multiple `if` conditions, you should use `elif` on ones that follow and then a final `else`. As your code stands, it doesn't consider the `if stopVar` block as the `else` before it is there. Hope the answer helps, if it does or another answer does then consider ticking the green tickbox next to the answer so the question doesn't resurface every few months please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works although I am not sure whether you want to `return` something if the case `'ATG'` is found, it is good practice that if one of your `return`s in a function returns something, then they all should even if it is `None`:

```
def get_orf(dna):
    """Function should take an argument (string) and find an ORF."""
    stopVar = "TAA" or "TGA" or "TAG"
    if dna[0:3] == "ATG":
        return "ATG"
    elif stopVar in dna:
        return dna[:dna.find(stopVar)]
    else:
        return dna

# Test Cases
#
# You may wish to add more test cases here
argument = 'ATGTGAA'
computed_result = get_orf(argument)
expected_result = 'ATG'
if (computed_result == expected_result):
    print ("Test Case 1: Passed")
else:
    print ("Test Case 1: Failed")
    print ("Expected Result:", expected_result)
    print ("Computed Result:", computed_result)
```

With `argument = 'ATGTGAA'`:

```
Test Case 1: Passed
```

With `argument = 'GATGTGAA'`:

```
Test Case 1: Failed
Expected Result: ATG
Computed Result: GATGTGAA
```

The `docstring` for functions is with `"""Text."""` rather then single quotes too so I changed that.